# Eiffel C Compiler Error

Tags: compiler-errors, eiffel

I am using the Effiel studio to code and I noticed at the ErrorList down the menu, there is an error message showing : "Error code: C Compiler Error

Error: External C/C++ compilation failed.
What to do: Check the external C/C++ compilation for details."

Does anyone good at Eiffel know what that means and how to debug it ?

Comment: When you double click in the red "C compiler error" message, you shoud see the error in question. Can you tell us what error you see there.

Answer (score -1):

In the output pane of EiffelStudio there is a selector for different output sources, including C compilation. Switching to it will give you the complete C compiler output that can be used to figure out what is wrong.